# Laravel 5 - Obtain html code stored in database

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I insert some code into my database. When I open the database and copy the field which holds the code, it paste like the fllowing

```
<div class="form-group-handle">
    <label for="text_input" class="control-label col-sm-4">Text Input</label>
    <div class="controls col-sm-7">
        <input id="text_input" class="form-control" name="text_input" type="text">
    </div>
</div> <div class="form-group-handle">
    <label for="textareaInput" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Text Area:</label>
    <div class="controls col-sm-7">
        <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" id="textareaInput" name="textareaInput" cols="50"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

So everything appears fine, just what I expect.  Now in Laravel I need to get this code.  So I do the following

```
$documentData = DocumentTemplate::where('name', $documentLink)->first(['form_data', 'form_data']);
```

And I pass this to my view.  Within my view, I do the following

```
{!!
    Form::model(new App\Document, [
        'class'=>'form-horizontal',
        'route' => ['projects.documents.store', $project->id],
        'files' => true
    ])
!!}

{!! $documentData !!}


<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('filePath', 'Document:', array('class' => 'col-md-5 control-label green')) !!}
    <div class="col-md-7">
        {!! Form::file('filePath[]', array('multiple'=>true)) !!}
    </div>
</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

When I check the output, it is a mess.  If I view source, the HTML looks something like the following

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/documents" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="uyg">

    {"form_data":"<div class=\"form-group-handle\">\n                                        <label for=\"text_input\" class=\"control-label col-sm-4\">Text Input<\/label>\n                                        <div class=\"controls col-sm-7\">\n                                            <input id=\"text_input\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"text_input\" type=\"text\">\n                                        <\/div>\n                                    <\/div> <div class=\"form-group-handle\">\n                                        <label for=\"textareaInput\" class=\"col-sm-4 control-label\">Text Area:<\/label>\n                                        <div class=\"controls col-sm-7\">\n                                            <textarea rows=\"5\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"textareaInput\" name=\"textareaInput\" cols=\"50\"><\/textarea>\n                                        <\/div>\n                                    <\/div>"}


        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="filePath" class="col-md-5 control-label green">Documents:</label>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <input multiple="1" name="filePath[]" type="file">
            </div>
        </div>

</form>
```

So it appears to add backslashes all over the place, and things like \n.

Why would this be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because $documentData is object laravel transfer it to json.. 
you should do this:

```
{!! $documentData->form_data !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply just wrap it with this function like so:

`{!! nl2br($documentData) !!}`